# Two files in same folder with same name - need to delete one but not both

Tags: ls, rm, sco

We appear to have two files in the `/var/spool/lp/logs` folder named "requests". 
One is owned by lp, the other by root.

We need to remove the requests file owned by root - how do we reference it?

Here's the output from `ls -l` command:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root     sys            0 Jan 30  2014 lp                 
-rw-rw----   1 root     lp          6584 Nov  4 06:10 lpsched            
-rw-rw----   1 lp       lp          3365 Dec 14 10:56 requests           
-rw-r--r--   1 root     sys      1668416 Dec 14 10:41 requests           
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys         1024 Sep 30  2013 requests.archives
```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`?

Answer (score 11):

If you have GNU ls, you can run `ls -lQ` to see a quoted version of the filename:

```
$ ls -lQ
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Dec 14 14:32 "requests"
-rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Dec 14 14:32 "requests "
```

To remove a specific file, first find its inode number with `ls -li`:

```
$ touch 'requests' 'requests '
$ ls -li
total 0
440 -rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Dec 14 14:32 requests
441 -rw-r--r--. 1 user group 0 Dec 14 14:32 requests
```

Here we have two similar files, one has inode 440, the other 441 (left-hand column).

For your case, find the file owned by root and grab that inode number. The `-xdev` (or `-mount`) option to `find` says to stay on the same filesystem, just in case you have a filesystem mounted underneath the current directory, to avoid catching any files matching in that child filesystem.

Then:

```
$ find . -inum 441 -xdev -user root -ls
441    0 -rw-r--r--   1 user group 0 Dec 14 14:32 ./requests\
```

Notice that `find` quoted the space character at the end.

and to delete:

```
$ find . -inum 441 -xdev -user root -delete  # GNU find
```

or

```
$ find . -inum 441 -xdev -user root -exec rm {} \;  # otherwise
```

Comment: Does SCO Unix have _any_ GNU utilities?

Comment: Don't know what it comes with but maybe an admin added them.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have two files with the same name in the same folder. It's likely that one has an invisible character in it (such as a trailing space).

My suggestion would be to rename `requests` to `requests.real` and then run an interactive delete. You can choose to delete the one you don't want, and then (if necessary) rename the other using a wildcard to the correct name

```
mv requests requests.real             # STOP if this fails
mv requests.archives KEEP.archives    # Temporary
rm -i req*                            # Interactive delete: "y" to delete, "n" to skip
mv req* requests                      # Rename whatever's left that begins "req"
mv KEEP.archives requests.archives    # Put this one back again
```